# Repeated Calls to a Function that Imports Data the First Time

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, import

I have several files with data in it that I need to use. I have written some code to import this data from one file, and then set up another function that depends on a list I read the data into to manipulate/recall the data.

I would like to generalize my importing function to be able to do the following:

1. Take as input a specific filename that I want imported
2. Perform the necessary importing (e.g. using the `Import[]` function) and manipulate the data to prepare it for use. For my case, this involves putting the imported data into a list.
3. Return a function that I can call which will be able to perform the necessary calculations to return the appropriate value from the list I imported.

The issue here is the variable I store the list in. As far as I can tell, either the list is a variable outside the scope of the function (a pain), or I need it to be a variable local to the function and I have to go through the process of reading the file every time I call the function (which is slow).

Is there a way to make a function basically "cache" some value, local to that function? I don't want to have to generate this list every time I call the function, nor do I want a bunch of extra variables lying around that I don't use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operator forms can be useful for cases such as this.

For purposes of illustration, we will start by defining a trivial import function.  To keep this answer self-contained, our function will use `ImportString` instead of `Import` (but this entails no loss of generality):

```
import[dataString_] := ImportString[dataString, "CSV"] // First

import["10, 20, 30"]
(* {10, 20, 30} *)
```

Then, we will create an example calculation function:

```
calculate[data_, n_] := data + n

calculate[{10, 20, 30}, 2]
(* {12, 22, 32} *)
```

Finally, we will introduce an operator form of `calculate`, i.e. a function that produces another function that can be applied to the trailing argument `n` alone:

```
calculate[data_][n_] := calculate[data, n]

fn = calculate[{100, 200, 300}];
fn[3]
(* {103, 203, 303} *)
fn[4]
(* {104, 204, 304} *)
```

Armed with all this, the requirements from the question can be achieved:

```
fn = calculate[import["1000, 2000, 3000"]];
fn[5]
(* {1005, 2005, 3005} *)
fn[6]
(* {1006, 2006, 3006} *)
```

This strategy provides positive separation between the import and calculation concerns, and yet those separated concerns can easily be composed into a single function that imports, caches locally, and calculates.

The variable `fn` that is used in the examples above could be global or local.  It is important to note that if `fn` is re-assigned, then the data that was previously cached will (eventually) be reclaimed.  The cache does not leak out into any global symbols -- not even global symbols of the form `x$123` which *Mathematica* uses to simulate local variables.

Comment: Clean, and exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Create and export some random data,

```
Export["test.dat", {#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 6.1, .01]];
```

Then define your importing function, storing the data as a local variable inside an interpolating function, or just as a list whose elements we want access to

```
importFunction[fn_?FileExistsQ] := Module[{list},
   list = Import[fn, "Table"];
   Interpolation[list]
   ];

importFunction2[fn_?FileExistsQ] := Module[{list},
   list = Import[fn, "Table"];
   list[[#]] &
   ];
```

Now we can delete the file after we call the function just to show that we aren't repeatedly accessing the file,

```
testfun = importFunction["test.dat"];
testfun2 = importFunction2["test.dat"];

DeleteFile["test.dat"];
testfun[.17]
testfun2[18]
Sin[.17]
(* 0.169182 *)
(* {0.17, 0.169182} *)
(* 0.169182 *)
```

The list is stored as an internal variable, not really clogging up the namespace,

```
?testfun2
```

> Global`testfun2

```
testfun2=list$5210[[#1]]&
```

You could also just use [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) to get the job done as well, then you won't need to define a new function for each file:

```
Export["test.dat", {#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 6.1, .01]];
importFunction3[fn_?FileExistsQ] := 
  importFunction3[fn] = Module[{list},
    list = Import[fn, "Table"];
    list[[#]] &
    ];
importFunction3["test.dat"][31]
DeleteFile["test.dat"];
importFunction3["test.dat"][23]
(* {0.3, 0.29552} *)
(* {0.22, 0.21823} *)
```

Again, I deleted the file after the first call just to show that it isn't accessed on subsequent calls

Comment: Nice, +1, but a `Clear[list$5210]` is going to ruin your day. I suggest sticking in something like `(Evaluate[list])[[#]] &` into your `Module`. However, that probably won't work since `list` is not at the top level of `Function`, but nested inside `Part`, so maybe something like `With[{l = list}, l[[#]] &]` or similar.